# Python create sqlite DB

Tags: python

I have the current code for a sqlite db creation:

```
 import storage
 import os
 import audiotools

 def store_dir(d):
     store = storage.HashStore()
     for root, bar, files in os.walk(d):
         for filename in files:
             filename = root + '/' + filename

             try:
                 store.store_file(filename)
                 print ("Stored %s% filename")
             except audiotools.UnsupportedFile:
                 print ('Skipping unsupported file %s') % filename
             except Exception, e:
                 print (e)

 def main():
     d = input('Enter the path to the music directory: ')
     store_dir(d)
     print ("Done.")

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

When this code runs I get a syntax error msg. Please help !
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include stack trace from the error.

Comment: and where in this code are you doing anything with sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to address here.

First, this line:

```
print ('Skipping unsupported file %s') % filename
```

needs to be this:

```
print ('Skipping unsupported file %s' % filename)
```

Second, you need to use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) here:

```
d = input('Enter the path to the music directory: ')
```

which returns a string object, instead of `input`, which evaluates input as real Python code.

Third, your indentation is off.  I'm pretty sure this is just a SO formatting error though.

Finally, you should use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) here:

```
filename = root + '/' + filename
```

That isn't an error though, just a tip.

All in all, your code should look like this:

```
import storage
import os
import audiotools

def store_dir(d):
    store = storage.HashStore()
    for root, bar, files in os.walk(d):
        for filename in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root, filename)

            try:
                store.store_file(filename)
                print ("Stored %s% filename")
            except audiotools.UnsupportedFile:
                print ('Skipping unsupported file %s' % filename)
            except Exception, e:
                print (e)

def main():
    d = raw_input('Enter the path to the music directory: ')
    store_dir(d)
    print ("Done.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```